# i have array and inside this array is many objects and i want to sort this array this objact keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api

i have array of country details such as flag name currencies capital timezone population and many more but in this array first country is kuwait that is start from k and i want to sort this array on the bases of country name

```js
const data = 
  [ { name: { common: 'Kuwait', official: 'State of Kuwait'   } } 
  , { name: { common: 'Palau',  official: 'Republic of Palau' } }
  ...
```

the path of country name

```
const name = array[0].name.common
```

Comment: Just you sort method with custom callback, array.sort((a, b) => a.name.common.localeCompare(b.name.common))

Answer (score 0):

you can use sort to do it

```js
const data = [{
    "name": {
      "common": "Zorro",
      "official": "State of Zorro",
    },
  },
  {
    "name": {
      "common": "Kuwait",
      "official": "State of Kuwait",
    },
  },
  {
    "name": {
      "common": "Palau",
      "official": "Republic of Palau",
    },
  }
].sort((a, b) => a.name.common.localeCompare(b.name.common))

console.log(data)
```